# How to make a slider

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, slick.js

[image: example]

How to make a slider that inserts items into a wrapper to the center, and the center item has a different size. Now i'm trying to do this feature with slick slider, but any sliders are welcome.

Comment: Google for `javascript carousel`

Comment: thank YOUUU
but not reallyyyyy that i needed

Comment: @Olian04 i just waited for your answer to be honest, and now i know the truth

Comment: [Have you looked here?](https://codepen.io/vilcu/pen/ZQwdGQ)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello, You can make this slider using Slick**

```js
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(function() {
        $(".center").slick({
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: "60px",
          slidesToShow: 4,
          arrows: true,
          responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: "40px",
                slidesToShow: 3
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 480,
              settings: {
                arrows: false,
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: "40px",
                slidesToShow: 1
              }
            }
          ]
        });
      });
    </script>
```

```css
@import "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.css";  
  .slick-list {
        padding: 70px 60px !important;
      }
      .item-slide img {
        width: 100px;
      
      }

      .item-slide img {
        padding: 0 0px;
        transition: 0.2s transform linear;
      }

      .slick-center img {
        transform: scale(1.3);
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center">
      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>

      <div class="item-slide">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" />
      </div>
    </div>
```